# Accessing Entity from a separate ViewController, not using Segues (CoreData)

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I've learned a bit about CoreData and I can insert a new object properly from the ViewController the Entity originates in, but I cannot do it remotely from another ViewController. Most of the other examples use a segue to get to it, but my setup is a bit different. It goes like this:

```
[Master View Controller] -[Modal]-> [Pick View Controller] -[Modal]-> [Input View Controller].
```

I can't simply use:

```
 UINavigationController *navigationController = (id)[segue destinationViewController];

    MySecondViewController *topViewController = [navigationController topViewController];
    topViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
```

at all. 
Code:

Master View Controller.m:

```
- (void)setDataItem:(NSString *)name :(NSNumber *)money :(NSDate *)date :(BOOL)dateOwed
{
    if (_money1 != money) {
        _money1 = money;
    }
    if (_date1 != date) {
        _date1 = date;
    }
    if (_name1 != name) {
        _name1 = name;
    }
    if (_dateOwed1 != dateOwed) {
        _dateOwed1 = dateOwed;
    }

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    OweInfo *oweInfo = [NSEntityDescription
                        insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"OweInfo"
                        inManagedObjectContext:context];
    oweInfo.name = name;
    oweInfo.dateowed = [NSNumber numberWithBool:dateOwed];
    OweDetails *oweDetails = [NSEntityDescription
                              insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"OweDetails"
                              inManagedObjectContext:context];

    oweDetails.date = date;
    oweDetails.money = money;
    oweDetails.info = oweInfo;
    oweInfo.details = oweDetails;
    NSError *error;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }




}


- (IBAction)submit:(id)sender
{
    NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    NSNumber * myNumber = [f numberFromString:oField.text];
    MasterViewController *topViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc]init];
    topViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;

    MasterViewController *master = [[MasterViewController alloc]init];
    [master setDataItem:iField.text :myNumber :dueDate.date :dateOwed];

  [self.view.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Everytime I try the above, I get:

```
2014-04-04 20:48:45.161 WhatIOwe[3688:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'OweInfo''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look up Dependency Injection and learn that pattern as that is what you should be doing here.  Whenever you create a view controller you need to pass a reference to the `NSManagedObjectContext` to that new view controller.  By doing so you will always have a reference available when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting an error when trying to pass coreData to a second (or multiple) viewControllers. This site told me that my viewDidLoad was being called before the managedObjectContext was being called. Add this code after [super viewDidLoad];   :

id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
context = [delegate managedObjectContext];

and I was able to use core data in multiple viewControllers.